# Setting up teaming on Esxi

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, vmware-vcenter, network-teaming

I have connected to nic adapters a standard vSwitch, and have enable 'Route based on an IP hash' on the vSwitch. For the physical switch we are using a cisco switch and have enabled LACP with nic teaming on two ports.

Now when we connect, the host stops responding. To bring it back I need to change the port on the physical switch. What could we be doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Using LACP on the ESXi end requires that the uplinks be attached to a Distributed switch, as Standard switches don't have those options.

You can still get teaming with standard switches, but need to enable a static team on the switch end, then use 'Route based on an IP hash' on your vSwitch.

Comment: thanks for the answer could you please be more clear on your second point or can point me to some web links that explain this further

Comment: A Google search for '[esxi teaming](https://www.google.ca/search?q=esxi+teaming)' yields very good information in the top 3 results, in particular the 3rd one which has a step-by step guide on how to do it with both Cisco and HP switches.

Comment: Also be aware that you need Enterprise Plus licences for your hosts to be able to use Distributed Switches.

Comment: ok, can you please advise if I can use multiple physical switches (configured with etherchannel) to support ROUTE BASED ON IP HASH

Answer (score 0):

The management interface overrides the settings of the vswitch.

Set the settings of the management interface of the ESXi accordingly, especially the hashing algorithm.

Comment: yes, I thought so of this. So decided to bring the management port out of the switch on a separate vSwitch dedicated to management. But still the host is having the same problem and yet the dual nic's don't work with the Cisco switch (LACP)